# how to display iframe's div over another iframe

Tags: css, html

i have 2 iFrames namely `iframe1` and `iframe2` and my `iframe1` contains a `div`.

In some instances, iframe1's div goes **behind** the iframe2,
but i want that my iframe1's div display **over** iframe2.

I'm using `z-index` in css to display div over ifarme2 but no effect.

Comment: I link to a demo, or a site would help

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript function that changes z-Indices of the divs in question at whatever "instance" you want the behavior changed.